# avg data of last week in a specific hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a sql query that return a AVG data of last hour. Example: right now are 11h this return the average of data at 10h.

Now I need to improve my query, I want the average data of last hour and the average data of all days of the last week in the same hour. How can I do that ?

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @begin_time smalldatetime,
        @end_time smalldatetime


SET @begin_time = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120)
SET @begin_time = DateADD(HOUR, -1, @begin_time)
SET @begin_time = convert(char(14),@begin_time,121)+'00:00'


SET @end_time = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120)
SET @end_time = DateADD(HOUR, -1, @end_time)
SET @end_time = convert(char(14),@end_time,121)+'59:00'

SELECT  u.name,
        YEAR(dpr.reading_time)              AS "year",
        MONTH(dpr.reading_time)             AS "month",
        DAY(dpr.reading_time)               AS "day",
        DATEPART(HOUR, dpr.reading_time)    AS  "hour",
        AVG(CAST(CAST(dpr.value  as DECIMAL(22, 5))/POWER(10, 5) as DECIMAL(20, 5))) * 1 AS "data"

FROM    example.users u                     
        INNER JOIN example.datapoint_readings dpr
        ON dpr.datapoint_id = u.datapoint_id

WHERE   reading_time BETWEEN @begin_time AND @end_time

GROUP BY u.name, YEAR(dpr.reading_time), MONTH(dpr.reading_time), DAY(dpr.reading_time), DATEPART(HOUR, dpr.reading_time)
ORDER BY u.name, YEAR(dpr.reading_time), MONTH(dpr.reading_time), DAY(dpr.reading_time), DATEPART(HOUR, dpr.reading_time)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to see the previous hour on each date for some period of time:

```
SELECT u.name, cast(dpr.reading_time as date) as reading_time_date,
       DATEPART(HOUR, dpr.reading_time) as "hour",
       AVG(CAST(CAST(dpr.value  as DECIMAL(22, 5))/POWER(10, 5) as DECIMAL(20, 5))) * 1 AS "data"
FROM example.users u INNER JOIN
     example.datapoint_readings dpr
     ON dpr.datapoint_id = u.datapoint_id
WHERE datepart(hour, reading_time) = datepart(hour, dateadd(hour, -1, getdate())) AND
      reading_time >= dateadd(day, -7, getdate())
GROUP BY u.name, cast(dpr.reading_time as date),
         DATEPART(HOUR, dpr.reading_time)
ORDER BY u.name,  cast(dpr.reading_time as date),
         DATEPART(HOUR, dpr.reading_time)
```

The important difference is the `WHERE` clause.  The first condition extracts the hour for comparison.  The second limits the results only to the past week.